# How to add extra save buttons

Tags: 7, users

In Drupal 7, my user profile page is getting really long. If someone sets or forgets a password, they don't see the Save button, and hence their password is not changed.
Using the Corolla theme, how can I add an extra save button right below the password fields?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement hook_form_alter() and duplicate the Save button.

Something like this should work:

```
function yourmodule_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Copy the existing submit button into the account fieldset.
  $form['account']['submit'] = $form['actions']['submit'];
  // Give it a high weight to have it show below the other fields.
  $form['account']['submit']['#weight'] = 50;
}
```

However, I suggest you also look for ways to shorten your form, maybe through theming or by using http://drupal.org/project/field_group.