# output same form buttone on same page - drupal_render($form

Tags: 6, forms

I try to duplicate form button on the same page. The button is printed like this

```
drupal_render($form['continue_shopping']);
```

The problem is that once I render the button, the second one is not rendered again later in DOM. How to overcome this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head, I would just duplicate the button in `hook_form_alter()` and render it as two separate buttons.

Some code examples here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1415334

And here:
[How to add extra save buttons](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3265/how-to-add-extra-save-buttons)